# Cross-platform atomic writes/renames without a transactional FS in C++

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems, cross-platform, transactional

I'm working on the app that needs to ensure consistency of its data saved to disk. I need to guarantee that the data never gets corrupt when dumped to disk. I.e. a reboot or app shutdown could happen when saving the data.

I know the steps that need to be done:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adioltean/archive/2005/12/28/507866.aspx

But I was wondering whether there's already an implementation allowing for this preferably in a cross-platform way? I presume boost::filesystem guarantees atomic rename (on Windows and POSIX), so wondering if I missed this functionality in boost somewhere? Thanks

UPD: I had hopes for boost::interprocess::message_queue but it just hangs on reading the queue if the process is killed in the middle of adding to the queue + memory mapped file takes up maximum size on disk, which is expected to be the worst case anyway.

Comment: Can you not just use a sql database that supports transactions or do you need it in your own files for some reason? Db vendors have spent a lot of effort guaranteing this sort of thing. Or is it the algorithm they use you want to know?

Comment: @rlb: I would prefer not to bring in additional dependency just for the sake of serialising very simple data structure. Besides, I need to have information about the data entries that get corrupted (i.e. can be used for restoring). So, I can see how I can implement this (see the link in my post). It seems that with SQL watching DB consistency would not be an easy task, where simple reporting about broken entries is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

you can get decrease of performance and/or lose all app data, if you will use renaming. May be store some key information (record ID and fingerprint, for example) after each record, and seek last correct key information when application is starting is better way?

Comment: I'm aware of this but consistency of data is of higher importance. I was considering saving my entries in a separate file along with MD5, so if I lose something it's only part of the data or last written record (i.e. trying to have a more granular approach where data is saved in "chunks"). But I was hoping it's been already implemented/tested by someone as this doesn't seem like a very exotic problem.